# Use of functional indexes in Oracle

Tags: indexing, oracle11g

This was a question for Tom, but he is busy right now.

I am not a DBA, just a simple Java EE developer, also I am new to Oracle, and I was asked to optimize some queries.

I have a large table, like this

```
create table test_table(
  DUMMY VARCHAR2(50),
  COB DATE,
  DATA VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Real table have many more columns, structured arround COB date. To process this table I use a view

```
create or replace force view test_view("DUMMY", "COB", "DATA") 
AS
  SELECT 
      DUMMY,
      COB,
      DATA
  FROM test_table 
  WHERE 
      DUMMY IS NULL 
      OR DUMMY <> 'INTFR';
```

I query this view by COB date mainly.

```
SELECT * from TEST_VIEW where COB = '15-Dec-2010'
```

And I want to make a specific functional index for query optimization, which would look like this

```
CREATE INDEX "TEST_TABLE_DUMMY_COB_IDX" ON "TEST_TABLE" (
  case  
    when DUMMY IS NULL then COB
    when DUMMY <> 'INTFR' then COB
  end
);
```

As I understand, this way I'll have all recrds for the day in a B*Tree index table, with the key of COB, will this optimize my general query use, or do I need some more magic to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work as you have it, since the expression in the index definition is not used in the WHERE clause of the view.  This would work:

```
create index test_table_dummy_cob_idx on test_table
( case when dummy is null or dummy != 'INTFR' then cob end );

create or replace view test_view as
select dummy,
       cob, 
       data
from test_table
where case when dummy is null or dummy != 'INTFR' then cob end = cob;
```

Whether this would actually make your queries more efficient depends on the data: you will need to compare to see.

Comment: There is only one way, to find out:)

Thanks.